# Assign image before li, using loop with SASS

Tags: html, css, sass

I want to assign 2 kinds of pictures before a li element, writing SASS. Instead of using nth-child() for each, or 2 different classes, I wonder if there is a smarter way, like a for loop.

Here is the css:

```
.class1:before {
    content: url('../images/image1.png');
}
.class2:before {
    content: url('../images/image2.png');
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<ul>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
    <li class="class2">text</li>
    <li class="class1">text</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `nth-child()`'s `odd` and `even` selectors like this:

```
ul li:nth-child(odd) {
    content: url('../images/image1.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(even) {
    content: url('../images/image2.png');
}
```

EDIT: You can use `:before` selector with `:nth-child()` as well. Try this:

```
ul li:nth-child(odd):before {
    content: url('../images/image1.png');
}
ul li:nth-child(even)::before {
    content: url('../images/image2.png');
}
```

Comment: There was a problem, with that expression all the text content will be changed by the images.